# How to accurately calculate age in redshift from a date of birth?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I ran this in Redshift:

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, '2022-01-01', '2023-01-01')/365) as age --1 (this seems right)
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, '2022-01-01', '2023-01-01')/365.25) as age --0 (this seems to undercount)
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, '2022-01-01', '2023-01-02')/365.25) as age --1 (this seems right)
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, '2022-01-01', '2080-01-01')/365) as age --58 (this seems right)
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, '2022-01-01', '2080-01-01')/365.25) as age --57 (this seems to undercount)
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, '2022-01-01', '2080-01-02')/365.25) as age --58 (this seems right)
```

It seems like dividing by 365 just... works which is strange to me and that dividing by 365.25 undercounts the age on the exact birthdate. Is that right? Does redshift just account for leapyears automatically?

Comment: When you say "This seems right" is it right or is it wrong?

Comment: Didn’t you already ask the same question a few days ago?

Comment: Why not just take the datediff in years?  Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: edge cases for leap years?

Comment: and I got a better answer by posting again. I think this is a fundamental problem with SO.